# Override icon in alert component in fiori fundamentals

Tags: css, icons, sap-fiori

How to change the alert type icon on the fundamental ngx. I want to use the warning type style but I want the different icon called `sap-icon--search`. I tried adding directly but not work:

```
<fd-alert [type]="'warning'" class="sap-icon--search">
    You search has zero results
</fd-alert>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply the style directly and instead you can override the content of `fd-alert--warning` with the `sap-icon--search` instead as follows:

```
.fd-alert--warning:before {
    content: "" !important;
}
```

Comment: Content is showing as a box for me

Comment: @plwgpcdmtgylobflef, Yes it is a special character from `SAP-Icons` set. Just copying as is should work.